# Calculate a field in Web2py

Tags: web2py

I need a calculated field that is the product of 2 other fields in the same table. The fields is `Total`, which is equal to `Price` * `Quantity` in an Stock table.

Would someone provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a [computed field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Computed-fields):

```
Field('total', compute=lambda r: r.price * r.quantity)
```

Depending on your needs, you might also consider a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Virtual-fields).

Comment: Thanks. Very usefull

Comment: Now I need to take value from another table in the same db. For example, I have a table 'sales' where I need to retrieve price from 'price' field at table 'stock' and fill sales.price. I use format and reference to take 'product' field, but I need stock.price too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question and provide more details. Note, the function assigned to the `compute` attribute can be as complex as needed (it does not have to be a one-line lambda), and it can retrieve data from other tables. Keep in mind, though, that if a computed value in Table A depends on data in Table B, the value in Table A will not automatically update when Table B is updated.